# What is the default url for 404 page?

Tags: url

This is an easy question.
I changed the URL-KEY of the 404 page thinking that it would apply to the whole website, only to find that the 404 page didn't work anymore.
Now I just need to know the default 404 page url so that I can revert the 404 page url-key key to the original one. The url-key circled in red in the picture is not the default one, I need to know the default one.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean by 404 url the not found path under `System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages` the path is `cms/index/noRoute`

The URL key of the cms page is `no-route`